# substitution of union in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm looking for a way to alter `union` in Haskell. The thing is I want to union two list of strings, but we are not allowed to use Import Data.List to use union.

What other way can we use to union two lists?

```
a `union` b
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a h/w problem.  So here is a hint:

assuming unique entries in the lists, take one list as the base, iterate over the other list and check whether each element exists in the base list if not add to the base.